# "Chat with live agent" popup window drops from the top in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, popup

This one site in particular [Total Training Online](http://www.totaltraining.com/online/howitworks.asp)

has a popup window that drops from the top of the screen on the right side. How can I create that in asp.net c# 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [jquery plugin](http://www.amirharel.com/2009/08/05/implementing-floating-div/) that allows you to achieve this effect very easily:

```
$(function() {
    $('#someFloatingDivId').makeFloat({ x: 'current', y: 'current' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that effect on the page you linked to, or a link that says anything about "chat with live agent".

Regardless, I would start by trying to find a jQuery plugin that gets the desired effect. Just hit up google, practically everything under the sun has a free jQuery plugin now.